# Bootstrap modal window change closing button style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap modal window and I love it.  However, I am trying to change the way the closing button looks, so I can get something like the close button that appears in this [site](http://www.desti.com/) when you click on "watch the video".

Is there any way you can customize it to make it look that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website uses [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

> FancyBox is a tool for displaying images, html content and multi-media
>   in a Mac-style "lightbox" that floats overtop of web page.  It was
>   built using the jQuery library. Licensed under both MIT and GPL
>   licenses